# Unit Testing Mvc6 TagHelpers

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created several custom Mvc6 TagHelpers and I would like to test their outputs other than on the app.

I've been trying to set up a Unit Test but I'm unable to mock the TagHelperContext.

```
[Fact]
public void TextboxTagHelperTest()
{
    var t = new TextboxTagHelper();
    var m = new Model1();
    var attr = new TagHelperAttributeList();
    attr.Add(new TagHelperAttribute("asp-for", m.MyProperty));
    var thc = new TagHelperContext(attr, new Dictionary<object, object>(), "");
    var o = new TagHelperOutput("united-textbox", attr, null);

    t.Process(thc, o);

    Debug.Write(o);
}
```

As anyone set up a Unit Test for Mvc6 TagHelpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .Net foundation did it, take a look at [TagHelperTest](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/release/2.2/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Test) in the aspnet/MVC repo on Github

Comment: exactly what I was looking for

Comment: The link is dead but there are taghelpertests here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/release/2.2/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Test